# No XAP file after buidling a Windows phone project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to build a windows phone project. When I build it in DEBUG, I can run it in simulator.

But I don't see any XAP file get generated. I only see it creates EXE file.

Can you please tell me how to generate a XAP file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1 you have to create the App Package.  Right click on the project and Select Store > Create App Packages.

---

[image]

Comment: Correct for Windows Phone Runtime apps. Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 apps do use XAP files. I ran the table in my blog entry at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/08/07/why-can-t-i-create-an-app-package-windows-phone-xap-vs-appx.aspx

Comment: I have windows universal app for win phone 8.1.After command "Crete App Packages" I get .appx file, not xap file. Where I can find xap?Thank you.